# Perl running as user "apache" cannot load DBD::mysql while other users can

Tags: mysql, perl, dbd

The site I administer has some CGI scripts that run scripts of the form:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

perl my-script.pl
```

my-script.pl uses DBD::mysql.

```
use DBD::mysql;
```

My scripts use many CPAN modules and I do not want to pollute the "system" Perl (5.16) installed by the Linux distro. Our security policy requires that httpd run as user "apache" and that apache not have a home directory on our server, so my solution has been to install Perl with perlbrew under a different home dir I have access to. Then the Apache config file for the virtual host sets some env vars to access it.

```
SetEnv PATH /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/bin:${PATH}
SetEnv PERL5LIB /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib  # this may not be needed
```

This works well-enough for loading most modules.  For example, apache can run:

```
perl -mDateTime -e 'print $DateTime::VERSION' # prints "1.52"
```

but if apache attempts:

```
perl -mDBD::mysql -e 'print $DBD::mysql::VERSION'
```

it barfs:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in @INC (@INC contains: /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2/x86_64-linux /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2 /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/5.30.2/x86_64-linux /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/5.30.2) at -e line 0.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

The error message "Can't locate ..." is misleading. I confirmed that DBD::mysql is available from the 3rd path in @INC:

```
$ find ~user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2  -name mysql -ls
16540213    4 drwxr-x---   2 user1   user1       4096 Apr 21 12:51 /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2/x86_64-linux/auto/DBD/mysql
16540211    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 user1   user1       4096 Apr 21 11:26 /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2/x86_64-linux/DBD/mysql
```

Furthermore, user1 can load DBD::mysql with no problem:

```
 perl -mDBD::mysql -e 'print $DBD::mysql::VERSION'  # prints 4.050
```

Therefore, I suspect that the above error message should have read "Can't load libmysqlclient.so ..."

libmysqlclient.so is located in /usr/lib64/mysql/

```
 ls -l /usr/lib64/mysql/
total 3076
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 16 11:59 libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmysqlclient.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      20 Apr 16 11:59 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.18
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      24 Apr 16 11:57 libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3135664 Aug 18  2019 libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    6758 Aug 18  2019 mysql_config
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 16 11:57 plugin
```

If user1 runs perl -V, the Linker and Dynamic Linking sections show the following:

```
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc'
    ldflags =' -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib /lib/../lib64 /usr/lib/../lib64 /lib /lib64 /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib64
    libs=-lpthread -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -lgdbm_compat
    perllibs=-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    libc=libc-2.17.so
    so=so
    useshrplib=false
    libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version='2.17'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs
    dlext=so
    d_dlsymun=undef
    ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC'
    lddlflags='-shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong'
```

If I run this same perl as apache, it will produce the same result:

```
sudo -u apache bash
PATH=~user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
perl -V
...
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc'
    ldflags =' -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib /lib/../lib64 /usr/lib/../lib64 /lib /lib64 /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib64
    libs=-lpthread -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -lgdbm_compat
    perllibs=-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    libc=libc-2.17.so
    so=so
    useshrplib=false
    libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version='2.17'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs
    dlext=so
    d_dlsymun=undef
    ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC'
    lddlflags='-shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong'
```

How come user1 perl can load DBD::mysql but apache can't even though both are running the same Perl with the same @INC paths and their dynamic library loading paths look identical?  Does anyone know what else can I do to get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you should never do

```sh
SetEnv PERL5LIB /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib
```

If you use `.../perl-5.30.2/bin/perl`, it will know to look in `.../perl-5.30.2/lib`, and that's the only `perl` that should look in that directory.

---

Ideally, you wouldn't do the following either:

```sh
SetEnv PATH /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/bin:${PATH}
```

The shebang of the script should point to the `perl` it's meant to use (the one with which it was tested and known to work).

In other words, use the following in the `bash` script:

```sh
./my-script.pl
```

And use the following shebang in `my-script.pl`:

```perl
#!/export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/bin/perl
```

What you are currently doing isn't terrible, but could bite you if you try to upgrade something.

---

Finally, `perl` can't find the module because of permission issues. Assuming the `apache` user isn't a member of the `user1` group, you showed that `apache` user can't access `lib/site_perl/5.30.2/x86_64-linux/auto/DBD/mysql` (and it might not be able access other pertinent files either).

Fix:

```sh
chmod go+X \
   /export \
   /export/home \
   /export/home/user1\
   /export/home/user1/perl5 \
   /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew \
   /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls
chmod -R go+rX /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2
```

Comment: The config should have read "SetEnv PATH /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/bin:${PATH}". I tried to obfuscate the real user name but I guess I wasn't careful enough. My bad. Kindly, change it in your response as well if you don't mind, so that I can comply with my employer's security policies.

Comment: thank you so much. I'll leave the history alone. I just don't want to leave a "welcome" sign. Meanwhile, I tried this:  env -i bash -c 'source apache-path; env |sort; perl -mDBD::mysql -e "print \$DBD::mysql::VERSION" ' and it worked, so apache _can_ load DBD::mysql if run from the command line.  The file apache-path sets the PATH env var.

Comment: Sets its incorrectly, from what you shown (There's no directory named `~user1`). Are you sure the right `perl` was executed in your tests? You should be testing using `sudo -u apache /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/bin/perl -mDBD::mysql -e1` Anyway, you showed the permissions being `drwxr-x--- user1 user1` for `auto/`. That's clearly wrong. Did you fix that as detailed in my answer?

Comment: I ran it again with more control over the environment. This time: "Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in INC (INC contains: /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2/x86_64-linux /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2 /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/5.30.2/x86_64-linux /export/home/user1/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/5.30.2)" There is no "auto" in INC this time. DBD/mysql.pm is available in the first path.

Comment: @inktomi, the error message says "Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql ..." I still think that means Perl it can't find the .so file for mysql when run by apache. It's there: "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3135664 Aug 18  2019 /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0".  Perl can load it successfully when run as user1 from the command line. It also works when I run it from my own personal account on the server. Only apache has trouble, even from the command line.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't ignoring you. I didn't see "auto" in INC. I'll try that now. I already followed your other suggestions.

Comment: Re "*I wasn't ignoring you.*",  I said the problem was that you needed to fix the permissions. Thrice. /// `auto` shouldn't be in `@INC` (only the directory containing `auto`)

Comment: I got it. You were right. Forgive me for not understanding sooner. I need to read up on Perl's module search method and how it uses 'auto'.

Comment: It must be where Dynaloader and XSLoader locate compiled XS (C) components of modules (the glue between Perl and libmysqlclient, in this case)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212372/discussion-between-lawrence-i-siden-and-ikegami).